# Salesforce - Time to Resolve a Case (Only Business Hours and Week Days)

Tags: salesforce, formula, salesforce-lightning

In Salesforce I have to date/time fields:
-ClosedDate
-CreatedDate
in the Case object.

I have another field which is a formula field(number) names TimeToClose, and I want that field to contain in hours the time since CreatedDate to ClosedDate , only summing the business hours and week days.
for example:

Date/Time Opened
4/3/2023, 9:56 AM

Date/Time Closed
4/3/2023, 2:11 PM

in thiis case the answer should be something near 4 hours.

I tried this but for the mentioned Case , the output is showing -0.63 and it does not have sense.

Thank you so much for any help.

```
ROUND(8 * (
  (5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(ClosedDate) - DATE(1900,1,8)) / 7) + MIN(5, MOD(DATEVALUE(ClosedDate) - DATE(1900,1,8), 7) + 
  MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(ClosedDate - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 16:00:00'), 1)))))
  -
  (5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900,1,8)) / 7) + MIN(5, MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900,1,8), 7) + 
  MIN(1, 24 / 8 * (MOD(CreatedDate - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 16:00:00'), 1)))))
), 0) / 8.0
```